# Applescript + Xcode "applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)" not working

Tags: xcode, applescript

I created a small script to control httpd/php/mysql and used XCode to create and link an interface to this script. Everything works ok. The problem is I'm trying to make the application window close after the red circle button is clicked, and is not happening. The app keeps running and only the window is closed.

I have tried using:

```
applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
```

The whole script is this:

```
script AppDelegate

#### PROPERTY LIST ####
    property parent : class "NSObject"
    property startApache : missing value
    property restartApache : missing value
    property stopApache : missing value
    property editConfig : missing value
    property editVHosts : missing value
    property openDir : missing value
    property resetConfig : missing value
    property editPHP : missing value
    property resetPHPConfig : missing value
    property startMYSQL : missing value
    property stopMYSQL : missing value
    property restartMYSQL : missing value
    property openDirMYSQL : missing value
    property resetMYSQL : missing value

#### APACHE CMDs ####
    on startApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/apachectl start" with administrator privileges
    end startApache_

    on restartApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/apachectl restart" with administrator privileges
    end restartApache_

    on stopApache_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/apachectl stop" with administrator privileges
    end stopApache_

    on editConfig_(sender)
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf"
    end editConfig_

    on editVHosts_(sender)
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf"
    end editVHosts_

    on openDir_(sender)
        do shell script "open /Library/WebServer/Documents/"
    end openDir_

    on resetConfig_(sender)
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to reset the httpd.conf to it's default settings?\n\n This cannot be undone!" with icon stop with title "Reset Configuration File"
        do shell script "/usr/sbin/apachectl stop" with administrator privileges
        do shell script "cp /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf.pre-update /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf ; cp /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf.default /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf" with administrator privileges
    end resetConfig_

#### PHP CMDs ####
    on editPHP_(sender)
        do shell script "open -a /Applications/BBEdit.app  /etc/php.ini"
    end editPHP_

    on resetPHPConfig_(sender)
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to reset the php.ini to it's default settings?\n\n This cannot be undone!" with icon stop with title "Reset Configuration File"
        do shell script "cp /etc/php.ini.default /etc/php.ini" with administrator privileges
    end resetPHPConfig_

#### MYSQL CMDs ####
    on startMYSQL_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server start" with administrator privileges
    end startMYSQL_

    on restartMYSQL_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server restart" with administrator privileges
    end restartMYSQL_

    on stopMYSQL_(sender)
        do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop" with administrator privileges
    end stopMYSQL_

    on openDirMYSQL_(sender)
        do shell script "open /usr/local/var/mysql/"
    end openDirMYSQL_

    on resetMYSQL_(sender)
        display dialog "Are you sure you want to reset ALL MySQL databases to their default?\n\n This cannot be undone!" with icon stop with title "Reset All Databases"
        display dialog "Type the new root password" default answer "" with hidden answer
        set root_pass to text returned of result
        if root_pass = "" then
            display dialog "Root password cannot be blank!" buttons {"Cancel"} with icon Caution
            error number -128
        else
            display dialog "MySQL DB will be recriated in the background.\n\nClick on reset and wait." buttons {"Cancel","Reset"}
            do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server stop" with administrator privileges
            do shell script "rm -rf /usr/local/var/mysql" with administrator privileges
            do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysqld  --initialize-insecure"
            do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysql.server start"
            do shell script "/usr/local/bin/mysqladmin -u root password '"&root_pass&"'"
            display dialog "All done!\n\nDatabase reseted." buttons {"Ok"} with title "MySQL Reset Utility"
        end if
    end resetMYSQL_

    on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
    end applicationWillFinishLaunching_

    on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
        return true
    end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_

    on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_

end script
```

Comment: The syntax is correct and the method should work. Is the delegate connected properly in Interface Builder?

Comment: Thanks vadian. Worked just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @vadian said: Have a look if the File's Owner's delegate outlet is connected to App Delegate (your script) correctly:

[image: File's Owner Outlet to App Delegate]

BTW this is the default after creating a new CocoaApplescript-App. I just copied the handler

```
on applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_(sender)
    return true
end applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed_
```

into the script and everything worked fine!

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked!